# Minimal requirements for ARC using

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, automatic-ref-counting

In apple documentation I saw that minimal requirements for ARC is iOS 4.3, but on WWDC 2011 video they talk that minimal requirements in iOS 4.0.
On what minimal iOS version ARC will work?
Will ARC work on iOS 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC is function of the compiler rather than the device, so technically it has nothing to do with the OS it is being used on. The difference between the two is the actual zeroing of weak references. Read [this](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-16-zeroing-weak-references-in-objective-c.html) for even more info about it.

Running an application that was compiled with ARC on a device with an OS prior to 5.0 will essentially manually zero out references rather than actually zero them out. The automatic zeroing is a core feature of ARC and is why you no longer need to call `dealloc` or release objects.

Comment: Yes and no. ARC relies on components which aren't shipped with, nor able to be installed on, certain versions of MacOS/iOS. Also - automatic zeroing of references and not needing to call release are two separate features.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know where you saw the bit about 4.3 (do you have a link?) - but in the ["Transitioning to ARC Release Notes"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) Apple says iOS 4.

Comment: I saw it when look wwdc 2011 video, 323 session. I think I were a little bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

ARC is a compiler level feature. So it should work if you are able to compile your code with the latest LLVM 3 compiler. Some very old code bases (mostly old C language third party libraries) that require GCC compiler will not work (such code bases are very very rare)

Zero-ing weak references, a run time feature that ARC takes advantage of, is not available on OSes before iOS 5/Lion. But ARC without weak references will still work.

Comment: Even new C libraries don't support ARC.

Comment: @Steve Yes,That's True.But Xcode have option to disable The ARC for Particular Files/Classes.

Comment: I guess @Steve is talking about static libraries.